# How to rewrite in the form of a basic rectangular hyperbola.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I was wondering how you would write the function $y=\frac{4x-7}{x+1}$ in the form of $\frac{a}{x+1}+k$.

I know the vertical asymptote is at $x=-1$.

I know that to find a (the dillation) that you usually need a point. The asymptotes are usually given in the question, but not this time. I also know how to change the form with linear and quadratic functions, but I seem to be getting stuck with these types of questions.

I tried solving algebraically, but I seem to always get stuck. I'm not sure what I should do first. I've tried plotting points but I cannot figure out what the equation would be from the graph.

When I mean algebraically, I mean that I tried bringing $x+1$ over to the other side, so that it would become $y = \frac{4x-7}{x+1}+k.$ However I do not know where I should go from here.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: No trick is needed. $$\frac{a}{x+1}+k=\frac{k(x+1)+a}{x+1}$$ so you just have to solve $$k=4,\quad k+a=-7.$$

Comment: "I tried solving algebraically, but I seem to always get stuck": Please edit your post to include your attempts. [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: @AnneBauval edited, thank you.

Comment: Your edit ($y - k= \frac{4x-7}{x+1}$) is not consistent with the context ($y=\frac{4x-7}{x+1}=\frac{a}{x+1}+k$). Did you follow my first comment, instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y=\frac{4x-7}{x+1}=\frac{4x+4-11}{x+1}$$
$$\implies y= \frac{4(x+1)-11}{x+1}$$
$$\implies y=4-\frac{11}{x+1}$$
Here $a=-11$ and $k=4$

Comment: @verygood101 I didn't get that, i got $$4x-7=4x+4-11$$ as we know that $7=11-4$ so $-7=4-11$